# Will I be able to buy shirts after beating the game on hard difficulty if I change the difficulty in the middle of the game?

Tags: the-last-of-us

So basically I've been playing the last of us witch is a great game but I just found out that you can buy in game shirts and stuff for the characters but only if you have beaten it on hard mode. I'm like maybe halfway through and I've been playing on normal mode so if I switch it to hard mode will it count as me beating it on hard mode? Also no spoilers. Seriously.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You know the answer?

Comment: I don't know answer for this game, but in all games, you should complete the game from begining to the end on hard difficulty, to get previligies. So, switching on hard mode won't count as beating it on hard mode, you should restart your game.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll have to begin and finish the game on Hard to unlock those bonuses.

Even if you finish the game on Hard, starting it on Normal will reward you for finishing it on Normal. This prevents players from gaming the system by changing the difficulty in the last moments of the game.

Comment: The tester in me is curious: what if you start on Hard, lower the difficulty to Normal, then raise it to Hard again at the end?

Comment: I imagine it'll always default to whatever the lowest difficulty you ever played at was, no matter the duration. If it were otherwise, I suspect we'd hear plenty of people doing just that to get the rewards associated with a Survivor+ playthrough without playing the bulk of the game at that difficulty.